# Should I use duplicate Shader programs with different uniforms?

Tags: webgl

Let's say I wanted to draw the same mesh hundreds of times with the same shader program, but different uniforms.

I have 2 choices:

- Create a single program and update all uniforms before each draw call
- Create a program per draw operation and set uniforms at init time and only call `gl.useProgram` before each draw call

It sounds like the later would perform better, but I haven't noticed a notable performance difference, but maybe I run into an edge case or this could only be a problem for mobile devices.

Comment: Without an example its hard to know what would be best. As for low end devices you are going to have problems switching programs sooner than sending uniforms.

Comment: Also, you don't have to update all the uinforms before each draw call. You only need to update the ones that changed. As an example if you had a single shader that took a projection matrix, a view matrix, a model matrix, material settings, light settings, you'd not need to set projection and view for every mesh and unless you're using different lights with different meshes you'd also only need to set the light uniforms once per frame instead of once per mesh.

Comment: @Blindman67 That's fairly surprising, considering switching programs requires just 1 function call. As for an example, I might add it when I have time again.

Comment: @gman You're right, I'll definitely separate uniforms that only need to be updated once per frame. I was also considering saving copies of last uniform values, but comparing all those float32arrays sounds like a bigger performance hit than it's worth.

Comment: You are best using instanced rendering. A single buffer to hold all the unique states, Uniforms to hold common state for all instances. For low end devices (many with far from optimal graphics drivers) a state change is very expensive, JS execution is not the slow point, Changing program is a more complex state change (reloads all execution pipes, all uniforms, etc) than pushing uniforms onto the pipes (on low end devices) Another solution is to sacrifice some source (shader) readability. Unique uniforms can be stored as an array and updated in a single call per draw.